# Find where there is no solution involving three variables

Tags: plotting, equation-solving, calculus-and-analysis, linear-algebra

I have two equations `SvA[zm, zs, zh]==0` and `tzmzs[zm, zs, zh, tb, b]==0`.
I will plot these two equations and find their intersection point given the range for `zm` and `zs` for some `zh`.

```
d = 3;
ag = 10;
pg = 10;
wp = 20;
f[z_, zh_] := 1 - (z/zh)^(d + 1);
tinteg[z_, zm_, zh_] := -1/(f[z, zh] Sqrt[1 - (zm^(2 d) f[z, zh])/(z^(2 d) f[zm, zh])])
SvA1[z_?NumericQ, zm_?NumericQ, zh_?NumericQ] := zm^d/(4 z^d Sqrt[zm^(2 d) f[z, zh] - z^(2 d) f[zm, zh]])
SvA2[z_?NumericQ, zm_?NumericQ, zs_?NumericQ, zh_?NumericQ] := (z^d (zs^(2 d) f[zm, zh] - zm^(2 d) f[z, zh]))/(4 Sqrt[zm^(2 d) f[z, zh] - z^(2 d) f[zm, zh]] Sqrt[f[z, zh] (zs^(2 d) - z^(2 d) )] (zm^d Sqrt[f[z, zh] (zs^(2 d) - z^(2 d) )] + zs^d Sqrt[zm^(2 d) f[z, zh] - z^(2 d) f[zm, zh]]))
SvA[zm_?NumericQ, zs_?NumericQ, zh_?NumericQ] := Module[{zmr, zsr, zhr}, {zmr, zsr, zhr} = Rationalize[{zm, zs, zh}, 0]; NIntegrate[SvA1[z, zmr, zhr], {z, zsr, zmr}, AccuracyGoal -> ag, PrecisionGoal -> pg, WorkingPrecision -> wp] + NIntegrate[SvA2[z, zmr, zsr, zhr], {z, 0, zsr}, AccuracyGoal -> ag, PrecisionGoal -> pg, WorkingPrecision -> wp]]
tzm[z_?NumericQ, zm_?NumericQ, zh_?NumericQ] := -1/(f[z, zh] Sqrt[1 - (zm^(2 d) f[z, zh])/(z^(2 d) f[zm, zh])])
tzs[z_?NumericQ, zs_?NumericQ, zh_?NumericQ] := z^d/Sqrt[f[z, zh] (zs^(2 d) - z^(2 d) )]
tzmzs[zm_?NumericQ, zs_?NumericQ, zh_?NumericQ, tb_?NumericQ, b_?NumericQ] := Module[{zmr, zsr, zhr, tbr, br}, {zmr, zsr, zhr, tbr, br} = Rationalize[{zm, zs, zh, tb, b}, 0]; NIntegrate[tzm[z, zmr, zhr], {z, 0, zhr, zmr}, Method -> PrincipalValue, AccuracyGoal -> ag, PrecisionGoal -> pg, WorkingPrecision -> wp] - NIntegrate[tzs[z, zsr, zhr], {z, 0, zsr}, AccuracyGoal -> ag, PrecisionGoal -> pg, WorkingPrecision -> wp] - br - tbr]

plots05 = {ContourPlot[{SvA[zm, zs, 0.5] == 0}, {zm, 1.3 0.5, 1.3139227026 0.5}, {zs, 0.992 0.5, 0.9976582043 0.5}, ContourStyle -> Blue], ContourPlot[{tzmzs[zm, zs, 0.5, 0.10000707106781259047, 0.1] == 0}, {zm, 1.3 0.5, 1.3139227026 0.5}, {zs, 0.992 0.5, 0.9976582043 0.5}, ContourStyle -> Red]};
Show[plots05]

plots04 = {ContourPlot[{SvA[zm, zs, 0.4] == 0}, {zm, 1.3 0.4, 1.3143183886 0.4}, {zs, 0.995 0.4, 0.9980176691 0.4}, ContourStyle -> Blue], ContourPlot[{tzmzs[zm, zs, 0.4, 0.10000632455532150657, 0.1] == 0}, {zm, 1.3 0.4, 1.3143183886 0.4}, {zs, 0.995 0.4, 0.9980176691 0.4}, ContourStyle -> Red]};
Show[plots04]

Table[ContourPlot[{SvA[c1 zh, c2 zh, zh] == 0, tzmzs[c1 zh, c2 zh, zh, 0.10000707095118766, 0.1] == 0}, {c1, 1.3139227026, 1.3143183886}, {c2, 0.9976582043, 0.9980176691}, ContourStyle -> {Blue, Red}], {zh, {0.4, 0.41, 0.42, 0.43, 0.44, 0.45, 0.46, 0.47, 0.48, 0.49, 0.5}}]
```

Now, the range of `zm` and `zs` will be

`[zm, some # enough to see the intersection point, c1 zh]`

`[zs, some # enough to see the intersection point, c2 zh]`

An example is,

`[zm, 1.3 0.5, 1.3139227026 0.5]`

`[zs, 0.992 0.5, 0.9976582043 0.5]`

where `c1 = 1.3139227026` and `c2 = 0.9976582043` are the corresponding upper bounds of `zm` and `zs`.

For `zh=0.5` (left side) there is an intersection, for `zh=0.4` there is no intersection.

[image: Image0405]

Note that the upper bounds `(c1, c2)` for different `zh` are different. This tells me that there exist an upper bound `(c1, c2)` for a given `zh` where the intersection point is exactly at this upper bound `(c1, c2)`. From the images above it tells me that this should occur at a `zh` between `[0.4, 0.5]`

To put it differently, I'm searching for the set `(c1, c2)` where beyond those values the two equations will fail to have a solution, meaning no intersection point as in the case of `zh=0.4`.

The upper bounds for `zh=0.4` is `(1.3143183886, 0.9980176691)`, for `zh=0.5` is `(1.3139227026, 0.9976582043)`. So this tells me that the upper bounds `(c1, c2)` that I'm searching should lie in the ranges,

`[c1, 1.3139227026, 1.3143183886]`

`[c2, 0.9976582043, 0.9980176691]`

`[zh, 0.4, 0.5]`

To make it even clearer, the behavior of the intersection point will move up to the upper right corner of the plot as `zh` varies from `0.5` to `0.4`. Although for the case of `zh = 0.4` the intersection point already "went out of the plot", i.e. no intersection point. A **zoomed in** version of the plot for the range `[zh,0.4,0.41,0.42,0.43,0.44,0.45,0.46,0.47,0.48,0.49,0.5]` is as shown,

[image: Table]

The upper left image is `zh=0.4` and the lowest right image is `zh=0.5`. You cannot see the intersection for this `zh=0.5` because it is zoomed in using the ranges that I said I know the solution must lie within. So, you need to look from the last image going to the first image, you will see that the intersection point gradually goes up to the upper right corner. Specifically, the intersection point for `zh=0.43` is closer to the upper right corner compared to `zh=0.44`, but for `zh=0.42` their is already no intersection point.

So the possible solution can be seen through plots, but is there any way to compute the approximate `zh` where the intersection point reaches the upper right corner (where the equations fail to give a solution)?

**Attempt**

```
NMinimize[{zh, SvA[c1 zh, c2 zh, zh] == 0, tzmzs[c1 zh, c2 zh, zh, 10000707095118766/10^17, 1/10] == 0, 13139227026/10^10 < c1 < 13143183886/10^10, 9976582043/10^10 < c2 < 9980176691/10^10, 40/100 < zh < 50/100}, {c1, c2, zh}, AccuracyGoal -> ag, PrecisionGoal -> pg, WorkingPrecision -> wp]

NMinimize::nosat: Obtained solution does not satisfy the following constraints within Tolerance -> 0.001`: {-tzmzs[c1 zh,c2 zh,zh,5000353547559383/50000000000000000,1/10]==0}.

{0.42461675303602813219, {c1 -> 1.3143183886000000000, c2 -> 0.99801766910000000000, zh -> 0.42461675303602813219}}
```

The value `zh = 0.4246167` seems to make sense since in the plot above, there is an intersection point for `zh=0.43` but no intersection for `zh=0.42` (at least in the plot but I'm not sure if you really calculate with the corresponding precision and accuracy set). I'm not sure if what I did here is really accurate, any help to find the accurate result? I think I just need to know which `Method` to use in `NMinimize` to get the most accurate result.

**Update**: I have modified the post to make the question clearer and credits to @UlrichNeumann for the conversation that made the problem clearer to me.

Comment: What means "cross the horizontal axis"?

Comment: @UlrichNeumann It means the intersection of the yellow line and blue line is located at the x-axis. So I'm trying to find the solution of the two equations located at the horizontal axis.

Comment: You're looking for an intesection in 3D-space `c1,c2,zh` , that's why "cross the horizontal axis" remains unclear

Comment: @UlrichNeumann Yeah, what you mean is correct, the intersection of `c1,c2,zh` in 3D space. I'm using a 2D plot to talk about a 3D thing which is confusing, I'll edit my post.

Comment: No it isn't a typo. Instead of `zh^2`  perhaps minimization of  something like `zh^2(1+c1+c2)^2` or `zh^2/(1+c1+c2)^2`  might be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**modified**

solution idea

For given parameters `p1=0.10000707095118766,p2=.1`(examplary) you try to solve the equations `SvA[c1 zh, c2 zh, zh] == 0, tzmzs[c1 zh, c2 zh, zh, p1, p2]` for the unknowns `c1,c2,zh` !

You know `0.4<zh<.5`. `ContourPlot`shows you the solutions `c1[zh],c2[zh]`

```
Table[ContourPlot[{SvA[c1 zh, c2 zh, zh] == 0, 
tzmzs[c1 zh, c2 zh, zh, 0.10000707095118766, 0.1] == 0}
, {c1,1.3125 , 1.3150}, {c2, .9965 , .999}], {zh,{.4, .45, .5}}]
```

[image]

The evaluation takes some time, that's why I took only three values `zh=.4,.45,.5`

**addendum**

The updated question clarifies the issue.
The questioner probably looks for a special solution in a known parameterrange which maximizes zh:

```
NMaximize[{zh^2, SvA[c1 zh, c2 zh, zh] ==0,tzmzs[c1 zh, c2 zh,zh,0.10000707095118766, 0.1] == 0
,1.3139 <= c1 <= 1.3144
,0.9976 <= c2 <= .99802
, .4 <= zh <= 0.5}
, {c1, c2, zh}]   
(*{0.249861, {c1 -> 1.3139, c2 -> 0.997738, zh -> 0.499861}}*)
```

Mathematica shows a message, which might be ignored. Increasing `WorkingPrecision&Co` improves this solution.

Comment: Oh, it took a very long time for me because I used range for `zh` but in your case you just used three points. However, is there a more general way to find the solution using say `NSolve` or any other approximation method?

Comment: My approach shows that for every `zh` you'll find a solution `c1[zh], c2[zh]` . There is no unique solution, `{zh,c1[zh], c2[zh]}` form a space curve!

Comment: Please see my update on the ranges of `(c1,c2,zh)` in my original post. I used your code using the updated ranges and there are no intersections for `zh=.4,.45,.5`.  `Table[ContourPlot[{SvA[c1 zh, c2 zh, zh] == 0, tzmzs[c1 zh, c2 zh, zh, 0.10000707095118766, 0.1] == 0}, {c1, 1.31392, 1.31432}, {c2, 0.997658, 0.998018}], {zh, {0.4, 0.45, 0.5}}]`

Comment: That's why I increased the parameter ranges a little bit

Comment: I have determined that the solution set I am searching must be within `[c1, 1.31392, 1.31432]` `[c2, 0.997658, 0.998018]` for `[zh,0.4,0.5]`. So the range for `c1` and `c2` cannot be expanded.

Comment: How did you determine these ranges? Sounds mystery!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128530/discussion-between-mathemania-and-ulrich-neumann).

Comment: @mathemania See my updated answer!

Comment: Based on my modified post and your modified answer. The correct perception should be, I'm trying to find in the parameter range the set `(c1,c2)` that will minimize `zh` not maximize.

Comment: See the behavior of the intersection point for `zh=0.4` and `zh=0.5`. The set `(c1, c2)` is higher for `zh=0.4` as compared to `zh=0.5`, although you cannot see the intersection point for `zh=0.4` in the plot because it is already out of the range that I have given. So the behavior should be smaller `zh` larger `(c1, c2)` so that is why the solution in the range should Minimize instead of Maximize `zh`.

Comment: I have tried using `NMinimize` but it just shows an error `NMinimize::nnum: The function value False is not a number at {c1,c2,zh} ={1.31425,0.997955,0.452392}.` Also, how can I tell Mathematica to minimize `zh` but maximize in `(c1,c2)`?

Comment: Mathematica is able to handle min-max-optimization : Look for  "Optimization\`FindMinimax".  Still you should clarify your question to define a  unique solution...

Comment: In your code you wrote `zh^2` in the first line, that is a typo right? It should Maximize/Minimize that first variable, so it should be `zh` right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128556/discussion-between-mathemania-and-ulrich-neumann).